# How do I check the number of cores used in a Pthread program?

Tags: pthreads

I created a Pthread program and executed it on a server. 
The number of threads is less than the number of logic cores of the server.
However, since it is the server, I am not sure the number of cores used to execute this multi-threaded program... 
Will the program always be executed with the same number of cores as the number of threads? 
How do I check this information?

Any help are appreciated!